# SQL Server convert xml to csv using CTE - nulls currently being ignored

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, csv

I am using CTE to convert xml to csv so that it can be exported to a file, however if I have an empty xml tag, this currently gets ignored.
Here is my initial solution courtesy of this previous very helpful post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23785202/6260721

Here is my sql:

```
CREATE TABLE EXPORT_TEST
    (
    DATA varchar(max)
    )

INSERT INTO EXPORT_TEST (DATA)
VALUES ('<EXPORT_DATA><ID>ABC123</ID><PRICE_A>5.6</PRICE_A><PRICE_B></PRICE_B><PRICE_C>8.1</PRICE_C></EXPORT_DATA>')

DECLARE @commaSeparatedValues NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @xml XML = (SELECT TOP 1 CONVERT(xml,DATA) FROM EXPORT_TEST)

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        rownr = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @commaSeparatedValues),
        Tbl.col.query('.') AS [xml]
    FROM @xml.nodes('EXPORT_DATA') Tbl(col)
), cols AS (
    SELECT
        rownr,
        Tbl.Col.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') AS Value
    FROM cte
    CROSS APPLY cte.xml.nodes('//text()') Tbl(Col) 
)
INSERT INTO EXPORT_TEST(DATA)
SELECT DISTINCT
     STUFF((
       SELECT ',' + IIF(ISNUMERIC(value) = 1, Value, '''' + Value + '''')
       FROM cols SSF WHERE SSF.rownr = S.rownr
       FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
       ).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)'
     ), 1, 1, '') as DATA
    FROM cols S

SELECT * FROM EXPORT_TEST
```

At the moment, it is returning:

```
'ABC123',5.6,8.1
```

But I don't want it to ignore PRICE_B, I want it to return an empty string:

```
'ABC123',5.6,,8.1  <--extra comma required where PRICE_B should be
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you really need the quotes around the text column? Not very conventional

Comment: This looks painful. Why use SQL for this? SQL is a special purpose language designed for DDL/DML database operations. Unless the XML was stored within a database, one perfect solution is [XSLT](http://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/) also a special-purpose, declarative language designed specifically to manipulate XML. And yes, it can [render CSV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365312/xml-to-csv-using-xslt) and other delimited TXT with ease!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        rownr = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @commaSeparatedValues),
        Tbl.col.query('.') AS [xml]
    FROM @xml.nodes('EXPORT_DATA') Tbl(col)
), cols AS (
    SELECT
        rownr,
        Tbl.Col.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') AS Value
    FROM cte
    CROSS APPLY cte.xml.nodes('EXPORT_DATA/child::node()') Tbl(Col) 
)
INSERT INTO EXPORT_TEST(DATA)
SELECT DISTINCT
     STUFF((
       SELECT ',' + IIF(ISNUMERIC(value) = 1 OR LEN(value) = 0, Value, '''' + Value + '''')
       FROM cols SSF WHERE SSF.rownr = S.rownr
       FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
       ).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)'
     ), 1, 1, '') as DATA
    FROM cols S
```

Using `cte.xml.nodes('EXPORT_DATA/child::node()')` in the second CTE will give as all nodes:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        rownr = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @commaSeparatedValues),
        Tbl.col.query('.') AS [xml]
    FROM @xml.nodes('EXPORT_DATA') Tbl(col)
)
    SELECT
        rownr
        ,Tbl.Col.query('.')
        ,Tbl.Col.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') AS Value
    FROM cte
    CROSS APPLY cte.xml.nodes('EXPORT_DATA/child::node()') Tbl(Col)
```

[image]

Then, in the concatenation we need to add check for empty string:

```
IIF(ISNUMERIC(value) = 1 OR LEN(value) = 0, Value, '''' + Value + '''')
```

Answer (score 1):

**This code works on a mass of records using XQUERY.**

- I'm assuming `char(10)` (Line Feed) does not appear in your data.
- I'm assuming the maximum length of the concatenated text is 1000 (I don't want to use varchar(max) for no good reason)

You can change both of these assumptions if you wish

---

```
declare @separator char(1) = char(10)

select  substring
        (
            replace
            (
                cast
                (
                    cast(DATA as xml).query
                    (
                       'for     $i in //* 
                        where   not($i/*) 
                        return  concat
                                (
                                    sql:variable("@separator")
                                   ,if(local-name($i) = "ID") then ('''''''') else ('''')
                                   ,($i/text())[1]
                                   ,if(local-name($i) = "ID") then ('''''''') else ('''')
                                )'
                    ) as nvarchar(1000)
                ) ,' ' + @separator ,','
            ) ,2 ,1000
        ) as csv

from    EXPORT_TEST
```

---

```
INSERT INTO EXPORT_TEST (DATA) VALUES
 ('<EXPORT_DATA><ID>ABC123</ID><PRICE_A>5.6</PRICE_A><PRICE_B></PRICE_B><PRICE_C>8.1</PRICE_C></EXPORT_DATA>')
,('<EXPORT_DATA><ID>DEF456</ID><PRICE_A>6.7</PRICE_A><PRICE_B>66.77</PRICE_B><PRICE_C>7.2</PRICE_C></EXPORT_DATA>')
,('<EXPORT_DATA><ID>GHI789</ID><PRICE_A></PRICE_A><PRICE_B>88.99</PRICE_B><PRICE_C></PRICE_C></EXPORT_DATA>')
```

---

```
csv
'ABC123',5.6,,8.1
'DEF456',6.7,66.77,7.2
'GHI789',,88.99,
```

Comment: Close, but you didn't handle the qoutes for non-numeric values :-)

Comment: @Shnugo, Ooch :-) (Although I've never seen a CSV that actually did that)

Comment: Yours could be simplified to `SELECT REPLACE(@xml.query('data(/EXPORT_DATA/*)').value('.','nvarchar(max)'),' ',',')` This works, as long as there is no *blank* in textual data. Why ever, the function `data()` knows nothing else then the blank as separator. That's a pitty...

Comment: *Although I've never seen a CSV that actually did that*, well, yes... Whenever you expect your delimiter being contained in textual values...

Comment: @Shnugo - I obviously didn't count on spaces not to appear within the data and this is why I used a separator which will most likely won't appear in the data

Comment: I didn't get your last comment

Comment: Just imagine a value like `I need this, this and that` as part of a CSV file with the comma as delimiter. Without quotes around textual content, this would break the structure, due to the comma in the middle. Either quotes or escapes...

Comment: Anyway, the other answer's got the acceptance, but I think we should not stay empty. +1 for your nice answer!

Comment: @Shnugo, lost focus for a moment... I'm used to `"`

Answer (score 1):

Besides the possibility to shredd the full XML and re-concatenate its values (there is an answer already), you might use `FLWOR-XQuery`:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<EXPORT_DATA>
  <ID>ABC123</ID>
  <PRICE_A>5.6</PRICE_A>
  <PRICE_B />
  <PRICE_C>8.1</PRICE_C>
</EXPORT_DATA>';
```

### EDIT better to read with a variable `$txt` instead of `($n/text())[1]`

```
SELECT 
    STUFF
    (
        @xml.query('
        let $r:=/EXPORT_DATA
            for $n in $r/*
                let $txt:=($n/text())[1]
                return if(empty($txt) or not(empty(number($txt)))) then
                           concat(",",string($txt))
                       else concat(",''",string($txt),"''")
        ').value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'');
```

The result

```
'ABC123' ,5.6 , ,8.1
```

Comment: Close, but you didn't handle the extra spaces :-)

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz, I think, the easiest for this was to wrap the whole call in a `REPLACE(this,' ,',',')` to replace each *blank+comma* with just a comma...

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz, One last thought... Now I think, one should use something *sure* within the `concat()`, something like `##dlmt##`, and replace this with a plain comma at the end...

Comment: If you trust ` ,` not the appear in a text, as in `text ,as in` :-)

Comment: This is exactly what I did. I used Line Feed but this will work for any string. You can see that I'm using `replace (...,' '+@separator,',')`